# Trying to configure ArcGIS Pro/ArcPy + VS Code, but can't activate conda environment. How do I correctly do this?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, conda, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to configure VS Code for ArcPy/ArcGIS Pro development, and things have been going ok so far, however I have run into an issue I am not sure how to resolve. I'm also curious to hear how other in the community have configured VS Code - I want to make sure I'm not way off base. Here is how I have configured VS Code:

I first cloned a Python environment from the ArcGIS Pro Package Manager, and then set the location of the Python interpreter in VS Code to the "python.exe" in my cloned env (which for me, was in this folder: %LocalAppData%\ESRI\conda\envs\my-cloned-environment\python.exe).

[image: Selecting VS Code Python interpreter]

And that was actually all I needed to do in order to run and debug a script. I am able to create a new Python debugging configuration in VS Code, set breakpoints step through the code, and get IntelliSense on all ArcPy modules & methods. However, there is still something I am not fully understanding, I think..

On VS Code Terminal launch, I get the following error:

[image: command 'conda' not recognized]

That looks to me like the system PATH environment variable has not been configured for Conda, and Powershell does not recognize the conda command. The Conda docs actually recommend not modifying the PATH env var, but if I do, I can resolve the error above, and the conda command is recognized.

However, that yields another error, "CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'."

[image: conda activate error]

Looking at the error message, I see that it is saying to run command conda init powershell, however, this also yields an error an I am stuck at this point, unsure how to proceed. Running VS Code as admin did not resolve the issue.

[image: conda init powershell error msg]

To further compound my confusion, I came across this in the Esri docs saying "propy.bat" or "proenv.bat" should be used, but I don't know how I would integrate with VS Code:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/using-conda-with-arcgis-pro.htm

Am I just completely way off base in my attempt to get VS Code configured, or am I going down the right path? Everything seemingly works by just setting the Python interpreter, but I'm not too experienced with Conda and don't fully understand what activating an environment does and how to ensure it's done properly in VS Code. The ArcGIS Pro installation of Conda seems to be a bit different than the default..any suggestions or sharing how you have your local development environment configured for ArcPy development in VS Code would be great!

Comment: Cross posted on [Esri Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/trying-to-configure-arcgis-pro-arcpy-vs-code-but/m-p/1220697#M65818), although no responses there yet.

Comment: activate in Conda allows you to switch between environments as needed. I always like to have a copy of the main ArcGIS environment in case something breaks. If I want to use a different environment in VS I will just select the interpreter for that environment, and I haven't needed to use the activate command within VS Code. Conda has a separate commandline prompt that you can use for working with environments. I don't think you need to have it working within VS to be able to run test and debug the python code.

Comment: User BrianWilson7 on the Esri Community forums provided me with an answer that solved the issue for me! [Link](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/trying-to-configure-arcgis-pro-arcpy-vs-code-but/m-p/1220814/highlight/true#M65823). I will give them the chance to reply here if they so desire; otherwise I will answer my own question with a detailed answer based off that and my other findings.